# Text inside bootstrap carousel active item aligned with and outside text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have this code:

```
<section class="container">
    Logo
</section>

<section class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x400/888&text=Item 1" />
                <div class="container">My intro</div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It's a bootstrap carousel with only one item. The item is a picture and over the picture a text. Here is the [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/616vjLz7/) and here is the [jsfiddle live example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/paulalexandru/616vjLz7/show/).

The thing is that i want to place the `My intro` text over the picture (with a margin top 10px) and in the same time to be aligned with the `Logo` text. How can i do this?

Comment: Did you try to put `My intro` in container class?

Comment: Yes, but it wont be over the picture. It would be under it.

Comment: Yes that would align it as Logo. You will have to add a custom CSS for it to be on top. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/xnjv8k1q/2/)

Comment: I have added a fiddle in my last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `anpsmn` posted in the comment, seems like this answer was right and here it is:

HTML:

```
<section class="container">
    Logo
</section>

<section class="col-xs-12">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="active item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x400/888&text=Item 1" />
              <div class="container test-over"><h2>My intro</h2></div>
          </div>        
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.test-over h2 {position: absolute; top: 10px;}
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/xnjv8k1q/2/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solved it!

Make both text absolutely position like this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/616vjLz7/5/)

html

```
<div id="logo">Logo</div>
<section class="col-xs-12" class="slider">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x400/888&text=Item 1" />
                <div class="myintro">My intro</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css

```
 .slider {
    position:relative;
}
.myintro {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:100;
}
#logo {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: No. It's not good. You removed the container class from Logo and that is the point here, to align it with that section with class container.